# Skin Color Detection in OpenCV

Tags: c, opencv

I trying to do skin color detection in Opencv.

1) First i converted the image into HSV from RGB

```
cvCvtColor(frame, hsv, CV_BGR2HSV);
```

2) Than i had applied skin color threshold in the HSV image

```
cvInRangeS(hsv, hsv_min, hsv_max, mask); // hsv_min & hsv_max are the value for skin detection
```

3) So it generates the mash which has only skin color but in Black & white image, so i converted that image in to RGB

```
 cvCvtColor(mask, temp, CV_GRAY2RGB);
```

4) so now i want the skin color in only RGB value.

```
for(c = 0; c <  frame -> height; c++) {
            uchar* ptr = (uchar*) ((frame->imageData) + (c * frame->widthStep));
            uchar* ptr2 = (uchar*) ((temp->imageData) + (c * temp->widthStep));
            for(d = 0; d < frame -> width; d++) {
                if(ptr2[3*d+0] != 255 && ptr2[3*d+1] != 255 && ptr2[3*d+2] != 255 && ptr2[3*d+3] != 255 ){
                    ptr[3 * d + 0] = 0;
                    ptr[3 * d + 1] = 0;
                    ptr[3 * d + 2] = 0;
                    ptr[3 * d + 3] = 0;
                }   
            }
        }
```

now i am not getting the image that i want actually that has only skin color in RGB.

Any Solution,

Thanks

[image]

1st Original Image
2nd Skin Detected Image in Black & White
3rd Output (Not Actual)

Comment: please do *not* use the outdated c-api, but the c++ one instead.

Comment: ohk will in future. but any solution on this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you're already quite close.

given, you have a 3 channel mask already:

```
Mat mask, temp;
cv::cvtColor(mask, temp, CV_GRAY2RGB);
```

all you need to do is combine it with your original image to mask out all non-skin color:

(and no, don't write [error prone] loops there, better rely on the builtin functionality !)

```
Mat draw = frame & temp; // short for bitwise_and()

imshow("skin",draw);
waitKey();
```

Comment: can we directly put & between to images ??

Comment: well, with cv::Mat, yes. else use bitwise_and()

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, without having to convert `mask` to RGB, you could `.copyTo()` passing the mask parameter

```
cv::cvtColor(inputFrame, hsv, CV_BGR2HSV);
cv::inRange(hsv, hsv_min, hsv_max, mask);

cv::Mat outputFrame;
inputFrame.copyTo(outputFrame, mask);
```