# How to guess the human races based on skin color

Tags: opencv

There are some questions asked how to do skin detection, e.g. [Skin Color Detection in OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22553715/skin-color-detection-in-opencv).

Now, assuming I got the skin already, what do in opencv I should in order to guess the races of the person in the image?  I don't need a really accurate result, but I just want to guess whether the person is black (e.g. african), white, or yello (asian)

Comment: Have a look here... http://stackoverflow.com/a/28796596/2836621

Answer (score 0):

Get some example images, segment them, and get the skin regions. Then take an average / median / small random sample of pixel values. Then cluster your example data, and see if the clusters correlate to the races you are trying to classify. That then tells you how to parameterise the classifier.

Comment: thx for the response, do you mean I can try following what is descrbed at http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/user_guide/ug_traincascade.html ?

Comment: That method is too general. If you wanted the computer to work out itself how to classify people into races, you would do it like that. But it is easier to do it by hand, at least for version 1. Write a temporary program to extract the data, then look at it, then write a simple classifier that works only for that specific problem (which could be a simple as greyscale level ranges).